# How can I connect to SQL server by just using local ip address

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently I am connecting to SQL server using `192.168.1.157\MyInstance`. I would like to connect to SQL server by just using `192.168.1.157` i.e if I type IP addressin SSMS it should connect properly using 1433 port number. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an SQL Client Alias as Goody said. Maybe better to put a name isntead of the IP address on the alias name.

Here below an screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the client machine you could create an alias to it with clicnfg.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set it when you install SQL Server. Just choose the "install as default instance" option during the installation.